# How to store image in solution using ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

I have an upload image function  that uploads images to the server but I am only able to add images into the server until the session ends. Once the session ends , I noticed that the images uploaded are not stored into my local solution and after some research I found out that we could make uploaded files be stored into our solution even when the session ends but I am unsure of how to implement it. I am very new to this and would appreciate all help given.
For now this is the code I have that allows me to upload my image:

```
 protected void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string uploadedPhoto = "";
        if (uploadImage.HasFile)
        {
            string savePath;

            //Find the filename extension of the file to be uploaded.

            string fileExt = Path.GetExtension(uploadImage.FileName);

            //rename the uploaded file with name

            uploadedPhoto = txtName.Text + fileExt;
            savePath = MapPath("~/Images/profile pictures/" + uploadedPhoto);
            try
            {
                uploadImage.SaveAs(savePath);
                lblMsg.Text = "Image uploaded!";
                imgprw.ImageUrl = "~/Images/profile pictures/" + uploadedPhoto;
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                lblMsg.Text = "Image upload failed!";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblMsg.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see your code is right because I used same way to upload and store image into folder like you.

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/Photos/" + f.FileName);
f.SaveAs(path);
```

May I see your full code ?